# How to improve async data retrieval and caching?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, caching, async-await

I've got the following code that retrieves data asynchronously and caches it for performance optimization purposes:

```
let cache = {}
const optimizedFetch = async (url) => {
    if (url in cache) {
        // return cached result if available
        console.log("cache hit")
        return cache[url]
    }
    try {
        const response = await fetch (url)
        const json = response.json();
        // cache response keyed to url
        cache[url] = json
        return json
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

optimizedFetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos").then(console.log)
```

The approach above works fine but if a second request to the same url comes while the first one is still awaited then a second fetch will be fired.

Could you please advice me on the ways to improve that scenario?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting question - I can't think of an "obvious" approach. You could keep an array of URLs that are in the process of fetching, and not make the call if the URL is in there - but presumably you want a result from that call, and there isn't yet one in the cache. All I can think of for that is to keep checking the cache every (pick some interval), presumably giving up if enough time passes. That code would be messy and I doubt the gain is really worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let cache = {};
let awaits = {};
const optimizedFetch = (url) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (url in cache) {
      // return cached result if available
      console.log("cache hit");
      return resolve(cache[url]);
    }
    if (url in awaits) {
      console.log("awaiting");
      awaits[url].push({
        resolve,
        reject
      });
      return;
    }
    console.log("first fetch");
    awaits[url] = [{
      resolve,
      reject
    }];
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => awaits[url].forEach(({
        resolve
      }) => resolve(result)))
      .catch(error => awaits[url].forEach(({
        reject
      }) => reject(error)))
      .finally(() => {
        delete awaits[url];
      });
  });
};

optimizedFetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
  .then(({
    length
  }) => console.log(length));
optimizedFetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
  .then(({
    length
  }) => console.log(length));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Your approach works great for me!

Answer (score -2):

Just save Promise as a value.

Working example:

```js
let cache = {}
let totalRequests = 0;

const optimizedFetch = async(url) => {
  if (cache[url]) return cache[url]; // return what we have

  totalRequests++;
  const fetchedRequest = fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      cache[url] = json; // <-- we replace "Promise" result with json result
      return json;
    });
  cache[url] = fetchedRequest; // <-- we keep Promise as a result

  return fetchedRequest;
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log('Setting request #', i);
  optimizedFetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos").then(result => console.log('Requests:', totalRequests, 'Result:', result.length));
}
```

Explanation:

- `totalRequests` is just for testing purposes - it shows us how many "real" fetches we made
- if we have an answer in cache - we return that answer
- if we do not have answer - we create new fetch and put it as answer

P.S. My answer is getting downvotes, but I do not understand why... It is working `cache` example. Please, people, if you downvote, comment above, so I will understand my mistake if any. Thank you

Comment: I might be missing something, but this doesn't seem to do anything at all to address the problem the OP is seeking to solve - which is that if a call comes in to the same URL as one which is still in the process of fetching, the request is fired twice.

Comment: @RobinZigmond special for that case I've added `for` in the end to test one-time requests (5 in my example at the same time to one address, but only 1 `fetch` fired)

Comment: @RobinZigmond I've added 2 comments to code. Maybe now, it will be easier for you. Thank you.